# Jenkins - Add additional build information (For example : Store the deployed version) in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am using Jenkin Pipeline jobs:

What I am trying to do ?

```
 1. There is a Job-1
 2. Job 1 has lot of builds.
 3. During the build run store some information in the build.Ex: Deployed  version of the application 
 4. Access the stored information from other Job-2. 
 5. From Job-2 I can able to access the basic build information like  BUILD_NUMBER, GIT_BRANCH etc..,
 6. Even i can able to add some information in the build description and able to access it from Job-2. But i would like to store and retrieve lot of information . So storing it in build description looks messy.
```

I don't want to use Files or other ways mentioned in the below thread.
[Hudson: What is a good way to store a variable between the two job runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419385/hudson-what-is-a-good-way-to-store-a-variable-between-the-two-job-runs)

So what I've tried :

```
1. Job-1 , Use envInject variable to define variables
2. Job -1 ,Updated the environment variables dynamically in groovy. Ex. env.version = '1.2'
3. Access the added environment variables from Job-2. 
4. Its not giving the correct updated value, Environment variables always have the initial value configured in the Jobs configuration page.
```

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: This thread may help the next person who comes down here. https://serverfault.com/questions/882158/jenkins-return-something-from-child-job